# Im trying to use try and except to accept only strings but it doesnt run, What am i doing wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to use `try` and `except` to accept strings only and display an error message if an `int` is typed in.

This is my code:

```py
name = input('Enter Your Name: ')
try:
    s_name = str.lower(name)
except:
    print('Please your Alphabets Only')
    quit()
```

Comment: you can use ```isalpha()``` method as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.lower()` doesn't throw error when you pass a string of numbers. So, your `try-except` is not working.

```py
>>> str.lower('ASD123')
>>> 'asd123'
>>> str.lower('123')
>>> '123'
```

To get your desired output, you can use `isalpha()`.

```py
name = input('Enter Your Name: ')
if name.isalpha():
    print(name) # or do whatever you want to do with name
else:
    print('Please your Alphabets Only')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason to use exceptions for that?

In case there isn't, you can just use `isalpha`.

In case there is, you can implement a utility that uses `isalpha` and throw an exception if the input is not valid:

```
def validate_input(str):
  if not str.is_alpha():
    raise ValueError('Input not valid') 

name = input('Enter Your Name: ')
try:
    validate_input(name)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
    quit()
```